# wrap and stretch inputs on form resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have two inputs on form in one row. First one should be stretching on form resize, second is of fixed width. But when form is narrowed to a particular breakpont, second input should wrap to second line and stretch as well as first one.
[image: gif]
[image: wide]
[image: narrow]

Is it possible to achieve using CSS?
Tried using grid, but it won't wrap at all.
When using flexbox the result is better, but still have to set flex-grow for second input and it's width is not fixed, while inputs are in one row

```css
.box {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 6px;
  grid-row-gap: 6px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(320px, 1fr) 200px;
}

.flexWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex1 {
  flex-basis: 320px;
  flex-grow: 10;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.flex2 {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">One</div>
  <div class="box">Two</div>
</div>

<div class="flexWrapper">
  <div class="flex1 box">One</div>
  <div class="flex2 box">Two</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/C4off/pen/WNKjJaK

Comment: You could use a media query to achieve this. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php). At 600px I've reset the wrapper to be display: block with the children at 100% width which forces them to stack on top of each other. I've set the width of flex2 to 200px to fix it at that.

```css
.box {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.flexWrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 12px;
  column-gap: 6px;
  row-gap:6px;
}

.flex1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex2 {
  width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flexWrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex1, .flex2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexWrapper">
     <div class="flex1 box">One</div>
     <div class="flex2 box">Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using flexbox only and the min-width proprty. Note .flex2 will overflow at container widths less than 200px

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.box {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 12px;
  column-gap: 6px;
  row-gap:6px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex1 {
  flex: 2 0;
}

.flex2 {
  min-width: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
     <div class="flex1 box">One</div>
     <div class="flex2 box">Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The final way this can be done is using [container queries](https://css-tricks.com/say-hello-to-css-container-queries/) which are [quite well supported](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries) now. The max size is applied to the container and not the screen as the example below

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: my-container;
  width: 60%;
}

.box {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 12px;
  column-gap: 6px;
  row-gap:6px;
}

.flex1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex2 {
  width: 200px;
}

@container my-container (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {outline: 1px solid red;}
  .flex-wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex1, .flex2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
     <div class="flex1 box">One</div>
     <div class="flex2 box">Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The case is that the form is resizeable itself, but not the whole screen.

Comment: I've added a flex box version. Let me know if this is closer to what you want.

Comment: Container query example also added

Comment: Adam, thank you very much. Container query seems to be a salvation, but I cannot use it in the project. I had to deal with it using a kind of hack.
I've set flex-grow: 10000 to .flex1 and flex-grow: 1 to flex2. So, in wide mode flex1 streches and .flex2 stays the same width, but when it skips to second line it becomes stretchable.

Comment: Cool. Glad you got near a solution. Any chance of an upvote? :-D